# How to define the width of a flag in a register

Tags: c, embedded

I am attempting to access the CMMND_CTR flag in a register called RESPONSE0. According to the documentation, the running flag is bit 7, the suspend flag is bit 6, the sleep flag is bit 5, etc, and I have defined these bits as follows: #define RESPONSE0_RUNNING      (1 << 7). Where I am having trouble is the CMMND_CTR flag is 4 bits wide (bits 3:0) and can't seem to figure out how to specify a width to the flag in the definition. I have posted the code below.
[image: Register and flag definitions]

Comment: Please do not post code as an image - [reasoning](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question). Copy it as formatted text into the question.

Comment: `#define RESPONE0_CMMND_CTR (0xf)` may be what you are looking for?

Comment: [A flag is one bit.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_flag) `CMMND_CTR` may be a field in the register, but it is not a flag. A mask for a four-bit field in bits 3:0 would be `0xfu` (15), or, equivalently `((1u<<4) - 1)`, which lets you write the field width (`4`) in the expression. Or `(((1u<<4) - 1)<<0)` to parameterize both the width and the starting position (`0`). The mask can be used with an AND operation (`&`) to separate the mask from the other bits.

Comment: Generally it goes: `(value & mask) << bitpos`

Comment: `According to the documentation` What documentation? Documentation of?

Answer (score 0):

> Where I am having trouble is the CMMND_CTR flag is 4 bits wide (bits
> 3:0) and can't seem to figure out how to specify a width to the flag
> in the definition

If CMMD_CTR is 4 bits, then you need to mask off those 4 bits. This means you need to set 4 bits (0xF), and as you have done in your other definitions, shift it to the appropriate position. Since CMMD_CTR is bits 3-0, then you need to shift zero bits.

```
#define RESPONSE0_REGISTER  (*(volatile uint8_t*)0x11)
#define RESPONSE0_RUNNING   (1 << 7)
#define RESPONSE0_SUSPEND   (1 << 6)
#define RESPONSE0_SLEEP     (1 << 5)
#define RESPONSE0_CMD_ERR   (1 << 4)
#define RESPONSE0_CMMND_CTR (0xF << 0)
```

And then you can read the bits like so,

```
uint8_t response0_cmmd_ctr = RESPONSE0_REGISTER & RESPONSE0_CMMND_CTR;
```